# How do I set this div's style in the style sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

```
<style type="text/css">
   #[':0:adId'] {        /* this does not work */
      background:red;
   }
</style>

<div id=":0:adId">Loading...</div>
```

Google Maps use this id format. How do i set the style?

Comment: Report a bug to Google. An id must start with a letter in HTML. ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name )

Comment: @David: I have a feeling Google did this intentionally :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to escape the `:` with a `\`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #\:0\:adId {
        background:red;
    }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a attribute selector, like so:

```
div[id=":0:adId"] {
    background: red;
}
```

This will not work in all browsers(you guessed IE), so you might have to include some javascript to do the trick there:

```
$('div[id=":0:adId"]').css({
    background: '#FFF'
});
```

(Uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com))